# Internet connection problem - Broadcom + Lenovo Ideapad + Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, internet, lenovo, wpa

I'm new to Linux/Ubuntu, and I'd like some help with setting up wifi with it. I have a broadcom wireless router (Broadcom Corporation BCM4312). 
This is the config:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:9e:e4:4e:a1  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:17 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:153 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:153 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:10927 (10.9 KB)  TX bytes:10927 (10.9 KB)
```

And these are my connections:

```
  *-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:f2000000-f2003fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:26:9e:e4:4e:a1
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.134 duplex=half firmware=sb v2.05 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:49 memory:f4500000-f450ffff
```

I spent the last few days reading and copying codes from here and ubuntuforums but nothing changed.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you've tried and how it failed (including error/warning messages and screenshots if applicable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you probably mean that your wireless *card* is Broadcom4312, not your wireless router (two very different things, and you confused me there for a second)

I've had quite a bit of wireless driver trouble myself (Macbook with a Broadcom card) so hopefully I can help you out with my experience.

SOLUTION 1:

Forget pasting codes. The easiest thing to do is enter the "additional drivers" app (check system settings if you cant find it), and enable the "Broadcom STA Wireless Driver" (BCM4312 looks like it is supported).

For me the installation freezes after a while, that's fine. For whatever reason the driver installs fine even though the Additional Drivers program will seem like it's "downloading and installing" forever. Force shut down your computer after 10 minutes (to be safe), and when you reboot you should be good.

SOLUTION 2:

You shouldnt need to use this, but I've had success with this in the past. Open terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

and reboot.

Comment: Dear Pipsqueaker, the solution 2 worked fine, thanks for the helps guys / gals!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to install all of the proprietary linux drivers, try just running "sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source" while connected to a wired connection, that will install the drivers for most of the bcm43xx series, and it looks like your is included in the list it supports